# Select an option by default only after the dropdown is fetched by HttpClient

Tags: angular7

I have a select field in app.component.html as follows:

```
<select class="form-control" name="status" [(ngModel)]="statusDesc">
          <option *ngFor="let status of statusList">{{status}}</option>
</select>
```

I'm getting status list in the ngOnInit method by making a HttpClient call:

```
statusList: any;
ngOnInit() {
this._http.get(this.APP_URL + '/statusList1').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.statusList = data;
        console.log(this.statusList);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error occured', error);
      }
    );
}
```

I want to set a default value 'InProgress' to the statusDesc in the ngOnInit method itself like follows, but it isn't setting the value in the html page. The word "InProgress" is definitely returned in the list from the URL. 
Also, statusList value is not getting printed on the console if I try to give console.log after the Http GET call.

```
ngOnInit() {
this._http.get(this.APP_URL + '/statusList1').subscribe(
...
...
this.statusDesc="InProgress";
console.log(this.statusDesc);
}
```

I guess this is because of the async call made by the GET method. Is there a way to resolve this problem?

I have tried this way also, but the result is the same.

`<option *ngFor="let status of statusList" [selected]="status == selectedStatusValue">{{status}}</option>`

Comment: Can you share the data of ```statusList``` ?

Comment: @ManirajfromKarur statusList has this data-  ["Warning", "Approved", "In progress"]

Comment: Make sure you are spelling it in right way, because the data given by you has ```In progress``` and in question you have mentioned it as ```InProgress```  (Confirm for space between two words).. I also made api call for your case.. So just change the code with option tag like ```[selected]="status == 'In progress'"```..

Comment: Here is the working solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agiiru

Comment: @ManirajfromKarur Great!!! Its working. Thanks :)